# In angularjs, getting Okta error before it even hits first line of $scope.submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, okta

I am new to AngularJS, and am trying to add an Okta login. I am getting the following error:

```
shared.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
at a.getDisplayName (shared.js:65)
at Okta.PageMonitor.<anonymous> (shared.js:3)...
```

I am getting the error even before I hit the line console.log below:

```
$scope.submit = function () {

      console.log('Error happens before this');
```

How do I find out how or why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/issues/189) when using the [Okta Sign-In Widget](http://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget) and the browser plugin. Any application that is hosted on `localhost` will currently throw:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
```